# SQLite3 db on iOS 9: read only error, how to write to the db?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I have an app that runs fine on the simulator. The SQLite3.db file is a resource to the project that is copied upon build. I can select, insert, update, delete when running in the simulator.

Once I have an iPhone as my target, with the iPhone still plugged into the computer, my NSLog statements in my data engine are showing me this db error:

> Opening database /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1347176D-066A-40FA-BDFB-D4087622806F/MultiView.app/P1-06-05-2016.db

I run a sql command next.

> Error: attempt to write a readonly database

Any help appreciated with setting the config of the build, or the path to the db, or some other thing I'm missing that will let me write to that db file on the device.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700508/how-can-i-change-sqlite-readonly-to-readwrite-on-the-iphone

Comment: I found a duplicate solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000311/sqlite-ios-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database?answertab=votes#tab-top